# wpf datagrid border brush not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am strugling to find a way to make this work:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="name" CanUserAddRows="false"
          IsReadOnly="true" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

I just want to change the color of the cell's borders, why it has to be so complicated? :/

Comment: "Not working" is hard to interpret. Is it failing in any specific way that you can describe?

Comment: the border cells keeps black

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<DataGrid
    x:Name="name" 
    CanUserAddRows="false"
    IsReadOnly="true" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"

    HorizontalGridLinesBrush="DeepSkyBlue"
    VerticalGridLinesBrush="YellowGreen">
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: man, that is what I was looking for! Thank you!, I did not realise the border should be set in the main tag. I spent hours in templates and DataGrid.CellStyle

Comment: I'm surprised CellStyle didn't work for you; I tried what you did and it worked immediately. But the black lines where still there in between. So I went to DataGrid looking for a way to turn those off, found `GridLinesVisibility`, and started looking for other properties with `GridLines` in the name. Bingo.

Comment: For my surprise, it worked when you asked. But it was not working. I tried of everything, however when I post the question, I cleaned up the tag for the question to be simplier. Althought the effect was not what I was looking for anyway

Comment: Ahhh. Very often, when you simplify the code to put it in a question, the problem goes away -- so always test the simplified code. Your answer may be right there!